# How Can we Render Html text in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have html text data and i want to bind this data in my gridview cell.

but my datagridview is not formet html text.

exp:

```
string htmltext = "<p>hi some text here</p>";
dgrow.rows[0].cell[1].value=htmltext;
```

In this case cell value of my gridview is contain Html tag also.
so how can I format Html Text in my grid view?

Comment: GridView from WebForms?

Comment: i m working with win form not web.

Comment: [`This link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView) will be useful for you ..

Answer (score 1):

I also recently had the requirement to render HTML text in a WinForms DataGridView control.

Like you I couldnt find anything out there that fitted my needs so created my own custom DataGridViewHTMLCell class.

You can find the code and sample project here: https://github.com/OceanAirdrop/DataGridViewHTMLCell

Answer (score 0):

In the mark-up (please note the Mode is PassThrough):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Literal ID="literal1" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

Use the RowDataBound event to find the literal and set the value:

```
void GridView1GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    //find the literal
    var literal1 = e.Item.FindControl("literal1") as Literal;
    if (literal1 != null)
    {
      literal1.Text = "<p>hi some text here</p>";
    }
   }
  }
```

Please forgive any errors, I have not tested the above.